# Repeating a task in android daily

Tags: android, wait, alarm

My problem is I need to call  a function that initialized things in android after 24 hours. If I do busy waiting then the initialization happen if the time period of the waiting is small like 1 minute but If I make it wait 24 hours the  function is not called.
The busy waiting code is

```
public void waitSecond(){
     Thread.sleep(1000);
}  
public void waitMinute(){
   for ( int i = 0;i < 60; i++){
        waitSecond();
   }
}

public void waitHour(){
   for (int i = 0;i<60;i++){
      waitMinute();
   }
}
public void waitDay()[
     for(int i = 0; i < 24;i++){
        waitHour();
     }
}
```

One way is that I use the alarm for this problem. But how would I know that the alarm has ended and then how could I call a function on this basis.

```
public static void setRepeatingSync(Context context) {
    try {

   AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), (24 * 1000 * 60 * 60),
                alarmIntent); //every 24 hours
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for AlarmManager?

Comment: Well I did not if there is anything interesting please share

Comment: There's your problem. **Read the documentation!**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the poster couldn't be bothered to read the documentation.